# Cannot delete a user in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, terminal, drop, sql-drop

I am new to [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL), and I have created a user called magento as described in the table below. Now I am not able to delete that user!

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| User             | Host              | Password                                  |
+------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
| root             | localhost         | *F4F8C81F12A316D6884269A228966F1E5763E16F |
| root             | mgaber-virtualbox | *F4F8C81F12A316D6884269A228966F1E5763E16F |
| root             | 127.0.0.1         | *F4F8C81F12A316D6884269A228966F1E5763E16F |
| root             | ::1               | *F4F8C81F12A316D6884269A228966F1E5763E16F |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost         | *63EDFEF710866BF1C20505D01DCEFBAA246750BC |
| ‘magento’        | ’localhost’       |                                           |
+------------------+-------------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

I have used the below commands.

```
mysql> drop user ‘magento’;
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for '‘magento’'@'%'
mysql> drop user ‘magento’@'localhost';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for '‘magento’'@'localhost'
```

Both are not working.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
mysql> drop user ‘magento’;
```

to

```
drop user 'magento'@'localhost';
```

You have to use the right quotes `'` and not `‘`.

Or use this:

```
 DELETE FROM users where user = 'magento'
```

[check this](http://www.craiglotter.co.za/2011/01/19/ubuntu-how-to-delete-a-mysql-user-account-via-the-terminal/)

Comment: Hi thanks for your fast response. I am using ubuntu O.S and i am running commands through ssh shell. I copied the command that you just wrote to my shell and it is returning the same error !!

Comment: this dont work also ? `drop user 'magento'@'localhost';` look edited answer

Comment: you have `‘magento’` in your table ? change it to `magento` without those quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop the user by escaping the single quotes as shown below according to [the doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences):

```
DROP USER '\'magento\''@'\'localhost\'';
```

```
DROP USER '''magento'''@'''localhost''';
```

Or, you can also drop the user with double quotes quotes as shown below:

```
DROP USER "'magento'"@"'localhost'";
```